# Creating a JSX list in React with an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I know when creating lists of data in React, you usually use the map function. But, since that works only for arrays, and I have an object, I'm not sure how to go about this.

So, I have the following object

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
length:3
__proto__:Array[0]
```

I'm trying to render the image from the url contained within each of these objects, and here is how I am trying to do it.

```
import React from 'react';

const EvolutionChainComponent = ({data}) => {
    console.log(data);
    for(let key in data){
        console.log(data[key]);
        return(
            <div>
                <img src={data[key].sprites.front_default} role='presentation'/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default EvolutionChainComponent;
```

The problem is that since I am using a for in loop, once I return the div, the code breaks out of the loop. I'm sure there is a simple way to do this by iterating over an object, but I'm not quite sure what that is since I've only ever seen React data iteration used with the map function on an array.

Comment: It seems like you are looking over the array of object and then accessing its keys, rather than looping over the keys in a single object since you are accessing value like `data[key].sprites.front_default`. In this case map is the way to go. I don't think you require Object.keys() to loop

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - Yeah, you are right. I completely missed that it was an array because when I console.log typeof data, it returned an object. And I forgot that an array is also a type of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to iterate over the object, You need to use the simple map method to loop over the array of objects

```
import React from 'react';

const EvolutionChainComponent = ({data}) => {
    console.log(data);
    data.map(function(item){
       return(
            <div>
                <img src={item.sprites.front_default} role='presentation'/>
            </div>
        )
    })

}

export default EvolutionChainComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.keys to map over the keys and return an array of elements instead of just 1 element:

```
import React from 'react';

const EvolutionChainComponent = ({data}) => {
   return Object.keys(data).map((key, index) => (
       <div key={index}>
           <img src={data[key].sprites.front_default} role='presentation'/>
       </div>
   ));
}

export default EvolutionChainComponent;
```

Comment: Hey, when I try to run this I get the following error

invariant.js:38 Uncaught (in promise) Error: EvolutionChainComponent(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.(…)

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting your time with this answer. I just needed to use regular old array.prototype.map